# D3.js - What is the best way to filter a d3.csv object to only include the top n (count) results?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I’m not sure I’m phrasing my question extremely well, which might explain why I can’t find a good answer out there, but I would really appreciate some advice!  I’m new to d3 (JavaScript beginner also) and am plotting some data on a bar chart.  Here are a few lines of my CSV:

```
Year,City,Sport,Discipline,Athlete,Country,Gender,Event,Medal
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HUANG, Shanshan",CHN,Women,Individual,Silver
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HE, Wenna",CHN,Women,Individual,Bronze
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ABALO, Luc",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ACCAMBRAY, William",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"BARACHET, Xavier",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
```

I plan to plot the Countries along the x axis, but displaying all of them is too wide.  After filtering on year, I still have 87 different countries

```
const startData = await d3.csv(‘olympics.csv’);
                console.log(startData);
                data = startData.filter(function (d) { return d.Year == year });
                console.log(data);
                console.log(d3.map(data, function (d) { return (d.Country) }).keys());  //Here I have 86 Countries remaining
```

I’d like to filter down to the top 15 most listed Countries.

The only way I can think to do this is to get a count for each like this:

```
var countries = (d3.map(data, function (d) { return (d.Country) }).keys()
countries.forEach(function(country) {
    console.log(data.filter(function (d) { return d.Country == country }).length);
}
```

…save that count instead of console.log, sort the results and use the top 15 in some way.

It seems sloppy and I’m hoping someone has a suggestion and would be willing to share.

Thank you in advance and I’m happy to try to explain further if this is unclear.

Comment: Do you need to use a specific version of D3 ?

Comment: I've been using v5 thus far and don't want to affect anything that I already have in place.  Aside from that, I'm not confined to a specific version.

Comment: If you do this a lot, try looking at the open fork of crossfilter, it's designed for this type of task amongst others - https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter

Answer (score 0):

For d3 v5 you can consider the [`nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests) function which can `group` and `rollup` your data. In your case your looking for the number of rows (length) per country:

First filter the data by year similar to what you do already:

```
// use Year as filter and set N for top countries
const yearFilter = "2012";
const n = 2;

// filter data
const filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Year === yearFilter; });
```

Then do the group and roll-up:

```
// group and roll-up
const topN = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })    // groups countries into arrays
  .rollup(function(d) { return d.length; })  // sums lengths of array (i.e. medal count)
  .entries(filtered)                         // passing filtered data to the nest
```

This results in:

```
[
  {"key": "CHN", "value": 2}, 
  {"key": "FRA", "value": 3 }, 
  {"key": "AUS", "value": 1}
]
```

But you can continue to chain operations: use a standard Array `sort` to put the countries with more medals first; `slice` off the top N and the return just the country names (with `map`):

```
// group, roll-up, sort, slice and map !
const topN = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })                           // groups countries into arrays
  .rollup(function(d) { return d.length; })                         // sums lengths of array (i.e. medal count)
  .entries(filtered)                                                // passing filtered data to nest
  .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.descending(a.value, b.value); }) // then use normal JS sort 
  .slice(0, n)                                                      // and take top N countries
  .map(function(d) { return d.key; });                              // and just return the country name
```

Here is a working example where I add 1 medal for Australia so we have something to remove from the ranking:

```js
// adding an single entry for Australia
// i.e. France = 3, China = 2, Australia = 1
const csv = `Year,City,Sport,Discipline,Athlete,Country,Gender,Event,Medal
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HUANG, Shanshan",CHN,Women,Individual,Silver
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HE, Wenna",CHN,Women,Individual,Bronze
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ABALO, Luc",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ACCAMBRAY, William",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"BARACHET, Xavier",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Swimming,Swimming,"FAST, Freddie",AUS,Men,Swimming,Gold`;

// parse csv
const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

// use Year as filter and set N for top countries
const yearFilter = "2012";
const n = 2;

// filter data
const filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Year === yearFilter; });

// group, roll-up, sort, slice and map !
const topN = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; }) // groups countries into arrays
  .rollup(function(d) { return d.length; })  // sums lengths of array (i.e. medal count)
  .entries(filtered) // passing filtered data to nest
  .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.descending(a.value, b.value); }) // then use normal JS sort 
  .slice(0, n) // and take top N countries
  .map(function(d) { return d.key; }); // and just return the country name
  
console.log(topN);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In v6 and above, the `nest` function is deprecated and is replaced for this use case by [`rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#rollup) - it does something very similar to `nest`. Here's an example

```js
// adding an single entry for Australia
// i.e. France = 3, China = 2, Australia = 1
const csv = `Year,City,Sport,Discipline,Athlete,Country,Gender,Event,Medal
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HUANG, Shanshan",CHN,Women,Individual,Silver
2012,London,Gymnastics,Trampoline,"HE, Wenna",CHN,Women,Individual,Bronze
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ABALO, Luc",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"ACCAMBRAY, William",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Handball,Handball,"BARACHET, Xavier",FRA,Men,Handball,Gold
2012,London,Swimming,Swimming,"FAST, Freddie",AUS,Men,Swimming,Gold`;

// parse csv
const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

// use Year as filter and set N for top countries
const yearFilter = "2012";
const n = 2;

// filter data
const filtered = data.filter(d => d.Year === yearFilter);

// group, roll-up, sort, slice and map !
const topN = d3.rollups(
  filtered,
  v => v.length,
  d => d.Country
)
.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a[1], b[1]))  
.slice(0, n) 
.map(d => d[0]);
 
console.log(topN);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```